# Textview inside Adapter not working

Tags: android

This code is not working correctly

```
  customViewHolder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

    Double rate=Double.parseDouble(customViewHolder.total.getText().toString());
    Log.e("rate",rate+"");
    Double newrate=rate-((Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getRate())-Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getDiscount()))*(minteger-1));
    Log.e("minusval",""+((Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getRate())-Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getDiscount()))*(minteger-1)));
    Double ratetext=newrate+(Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getRate())-Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getDiscount()))*minteger;
    Log.e("ratetext",ratetext+"");

    Double discrate=Double.parseDouble(customViewHolder.disctotal.getText().toString());
                        Double newdiscrate=discrate-(Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getDiscount())*(minteger-1));
                        Double disctext=newdiscrate+Double.parseDouble(feedItem.getDiscount())*minteger;

    Log.e("ratettttttttext",ratetext+"");
    customViewHolder.total.setText(""+ratetext);// not working
    ustomViewHolder.totalnew.setText(ratetext+"");// not working
    customViewHolder.disctotal.setText(disctext+"");// not working

    }
 });
```

In this `Adapter`, inside `onbindViewHolder` my `TextView` not setting with the newvalue. Why it is happen?

Comment: Post your whole adapter's code.

Comment: coming data in logcats or not????

Comment: it is showing inside logcat.but textview not setting

Comment: @JeevaV put ur whole adapter code here...i think you are setting value of textview in two places..one in bindviewholder outside from clicklistener and other inside clicklistener

Answer (score 0):

call **notifyDataSetChanged** after setting value,it will refresh the adapter

```
customViewHolder.total.setText(""+ratetext);// not working
ustomViewHolder.totalnew.setText(ratetext+"");// not working
customViewHolder.disctotal.setText(disctext+"");
adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the View you get in onClick to your custom ViewHolder and change the values in that

```
CustomViewHolder viewHolder = (CustomViewHolder) v;
viewHolder.total.setText(total);
```